# Can't open new Chrome instance if headless_chrome is running

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to open a new Google Chrome window when running `headless_chrome` with no previously opened browser windows?

**NOT WORKING SCENARIO**

- No Google Chrome instances opened.
- Running `rspec some_spec.rb` with `headless_chrome`.

I can't run a new instance of Google Chrome: clicking on the app icon just doesn't work, and right-clicking on it doesn't propose the option "Open a new window".

[image]

**WORKING SCENARIO**

- One or multiple Google Chrome instances previously opened.
- Running `rspec some_spec.rb` with `headless_chrome`.

I'm able to open new instances of Google Chrome.

[image]